# Delphi7, Indy10, Openssl and Intraweb

Tags: delphi, ssl, intraweb

I've to modify a very old app written in Delphi7 and Intraweb to upgrade to the last security requirements (Tls 1.2)
I'm using delphi7, intraweb 8.0.2 (very old, sigh) , indy 10, openssl,
so I started making some simple apps just to test all this components.

If i make a simple server using only Delphi, Indy10, Openssl,
taken from

http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/openssl-1.0.2c-i386-win32

it works perfectly.

If I atttempt to use Intraweb, specifying port 443 in the ssloptions, as I start the application I get the following error:

```
exception EidOSSLCouldNotLoadSSLLibray in module Standalone.exe
at 000EE8E1. Could not load SSL Libray
```

I tried also to intercept the internal error message using the function
WhichFailedToLoad, but it returns an empty string.

So this is the question:

Is it possible to use openssl 1.0.2.c (and also next versions) using
Delphi7, Intraweb 8.0.2 and indy10 ?
It seems to me it's  a problem of Intraweb, since the combo Delphi+Indy+Openssl works correctly.

I'd rather not to upgrade to newer versions of intraweb, 
but if this is a must we could think to make such an upgrade.

Best regards.

Maurizio

Comment: Has a lot of work of the project been done with IntraWeb? I'm curious about the main reason for sticking with (the old version of) IntraWeb. If there isn't really a strong reason, I would humbly suggest to have a look at [xxm](http://xxm.sf.net/). It's written in Delphi 7 as well, and integrates well into IIS or HTTPAPI (and others, but these two it's straight forward to set up TLS).

Comment: IntraWeb uses a private internal copy of Indy, where all of the Indy units have been renamed to use an `In` prefix instead of `Id`.  So make sure you are calling IntraWeb's version of `WhichFailedToLoad()`, not Indy's version. That might account for the blank string. Also, IntraWeb 8 is very old, so I suspect it was using Indy 9 (or even 8) instead of 10. Back then, Indy 8 and some 9 versions depended on **custom** OpenSSL DLLs that exported extra Indy-added functions (which were later removed when Indy started using the standard DLLs).  You might have to use those custom DLLs with IntraWeb 8.

Comment: The custom DLLs are in Fulgan's SSL archive folder.